# typing.Union allows for callables as its type arguments

Tags: python, python-3.7, typing, callable

I am concerned about why callables are valid type arguments to pass to `Union[]` (as well as some other `typing._GenericAlias` objects)? What is the intended purpose of this?

```
>>> def foo(): pass
...
>>> Union[foo, print]
typing.Union[foo, <built-in function print>]
```

After some further investigation I found that, for some reason, the code in Python 3.7.0 stdlib does not match one located in `typing` [GitHub repository](https://github.com/python/typing/). But `typing` module that my current Python installation uses allows callables explicitly:

```
def _type_check(arg, msg, is_argument=True):
    <...>
    if not callable(arg):
        raise TypeError(f"{msg} Got {arg!r:.100}.")
    return arg
```

Comment: Why should it be forbidden?

Comment: Because callables are not types and cannot be used with `isinstance()` checks, while `typing._GenericAlias` objects (generally) could.